# cant verify id token gotten from android application

Tags: java, android, servlets, google-oauth

am using google sign-in to access to some clients profiles in a web server
for the browser acces is work just fine
from an android client application am getting the idtoken and am sending it to the server,but i can get it work what ever i do
 there is 3 id's at the console developper
  https://pasteboard.co/IZHiS6h.png
and the  verifier

```
package com.mypackage.beans;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken.Payload;

import java.util.Collections;

public class IdTokenVerifierAndParserAndroid {
private static Payload payload =null;
    public static GoogleIdToken.Payload getPayload (String tokenString,String 
google_client_id) throws Exception {


    final NetHttpTransport transport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    final JacksonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(transport, jsonFactory)
// Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend:
    .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(google_client_id))
    .build();

GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify(tokenString);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

well the problem was in the SH1-A of API Key,the one in the IDE is diffrent from that of the application signed by google  that we can fined in the app signing in the application dashboard